# Is there a javascript/NodeJS client for elastic-search that can be used in React-Native as well

Tags: react-native, api, elasticsearch, kibana

I am developing an app in react-native.
I have an elastic-search server up and running in AWS cloud.
Right now, It's possible to run queries using Kibana dev tools.

Now I want to query that elastic-search server in react-native mobile app. I want to make API calls to that server.
How can I do that ?

I tried using this client https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js but it didn't helped me because client itself was not working in react-native as its showed me many error like **http** or **os** cannot be found inside project.

I installed these packages using ***npm*** but it still didn't solved the problem.

I want to know what's the right approach for doing this and is it even possible to query elastic-search using this NodeJS client?

Comment: which version of Elasticsearch you are using ? is it `Opensearch` as you menioned about AWS?

Comment: @SagarPatel I am using Elastic Search 7.10